# Strange onClick highlighting for CardView

Tags: android, xml

I'm running into some strange behavior for a CardView that I have set as clickable. Clicking it highlights all the views inside the card slightly differently, which makes it look weird when you stop pressing on the card.

[Here is what it looks like when the card is clicked](https://gfycat.com/ConcreteShimmeringDormouse). Ideally I'd like the entire card to turn pink when your finger is on it. When you let go, the card evenly fades back to white.

Any advice is appreciated!

**card_class.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:background="@drawable/button_rect_list_normal">
        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:background="@drawable/button_rect_list_normal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/class_name"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingStart="16dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:paddingTop="18dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/text"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:text="@string/classname_placeholder"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_rect_list_normal"
                    android:paddingBottom="18dp"
                    android:autoText="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/class_teacher"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingStart="16dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="24dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/secondary2"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:text="@string/teacher_placeholder"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_rect_list_normal" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="@string/period_placeholder"
                android:id="@+id/class_period"
                android:elegantTextHeight="false"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:textSize="57sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**button_rect_list_normal.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

**pressed.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#F44336"/>
</shape>
```

**selected.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFCDD2"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be applying your drawable to the root `CardView` if you want the background to change for the whole card - I'm not sure why you have different background drawables applied to multiple `ViewGroup`'s.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="@drawable/button_rect_list_normal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

**EDIT:** Changed `android:background` to `android:foreground`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, when I apply the background drawable to only the CardView, it is not highlighted when I click on it. I am using this card in a RecyclerView, where in the adapter I have set an onClickListener for the CardView.

Comment: Try the above; however it's worth noting that `android:clickable` will prevent your onClickListener for the `CardView` from working.

Comment: Thank you, changing background to foreground works and now the whole card highlights properly. In regards to my onClickListener not working, it seems to work still.